# How to check the value of a select list item in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I need to hide/show certain divs if points is selected. I get a JS error that PlanMetric is null when I am doing the following:

I have an MVC model coming in with:

```
  public int PlanMetric {get; set;}

  //this is in a setter method    
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Metrics = new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem {Text = "Foo", Value = "1"},
      new SelectListItem {Text = "Bar", Value = "2"}
  };
```

On the page I have:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PlanMetric)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PlanMetric, 
                          Model.Metrics, new { 
                          data_bind = "value: PlanMetric, 
                          options: Metrics, 
                          optionsText: 'Text',
                          optionsValue: 'Value'"  })
```

In my _layout page I have:

```
  //Merge JS/MVC View Model
        var vmMVC = ko.mapping.fromJSON(
                   '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                              Model, Formatting.None,
                              Constants.JsonDatabaseSettings))');
        var vmJS = new ViewModel();

        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(vmJS, vmMVC);

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Then in my JS View Model I have:

```
      var self = this;
self.isPointsSelected = ko.computed(function() {
    return vm.PlanMetric() == 2;
});
```

Why isn't knockout binding the value of the selected item to PlanMetric?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `return self.PlanMetric() == 2;`?

Comment: Yes!! I knew it was something small. Add that as an answer and I will go cry in a corner now

Comment: Happens! No need to cry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `vm` with `self` in this code:

```
var self = this;
self.isPointsSelected = ko.computed(function() {
    return vm.PlanMetric() == 2; // <-- should be return self.PlanMetric() == 2;
});
```